# Swift generic function error?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Here is my code:

```
func swapTwoValues<T>(inout a: T, inout b: T){
  let temp = a
  a = b
  b = temp
}
var aInt = 5
var bInt = 98
swapTwoValues(&aInt, &bInt)
```

When call function swapTwoValues(),"T" is  Int Type

But when i change this code to

```
func swapTwoValues<T,S:String>(inout a: T, inout b: T , inout c: S ){
  let temp = a
  a = b
  b = temp
  c = "Hi"
}
var aInt  = 5
var bInt  = 98
var cStr  = "Hello"
swapTwoValues(&aInt, &bInt,&cStr)
```

This will show error,but why?

I set "S" to String type ,it's seem correct

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn’t work is because the `A: B` syntax is there to require that a generic placeholder represents any type that conforms to a protocol or inherits from a base class.  Since `String` is a struct, not a protocol or class, you get an error ("Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type ‘String’”).  You’d get the same if you tried an enum like `Optional`.

Why is this?  The purpose of generics is to allow you to write code for more than one possible type, and then have Swift at compile time allow that function to be applied to multiple different types that meet that requirement.

Structs do not allow inheritance (only classes do).  So when you say `func f<S: String>(c: S)` you would be defining a generic placeholder `S`, that could only ever represent a type of `String` and no other type.  This would be pointless – you may as well specify `String` as a non generic parameter i.e. `func f(s: String)` because there is no possible other type it could be.

Classes on the other hand do allow inheritance, so if you had a class `MyClass` you could write `func f:<S: MyClass>(c: S)` because at compile-time, maybe you could pass in `MyInheritedClass`, a class that inherits from `MyClass`.

Structs can conform to protocols though.  So for example, suppose you wanted to write something that swapped the values only if one were greater than the other:

```
func swapIfGreater<T: Comparable>(inout a: T, inout b: T) {
    // this is allowed because conformance to the the 
    // Comparable protocol guarantees > is available
    if a > b {
        // avoid temporaries with this one weird trick :)
        (a, b) = (b, a)
    }
}

// i and j are Ints (a kind of struct)
var i = 40, j = 30
swapIfGreater(&i, &j)

// s1 and s2 are Strings
var s1 = "zebra", s2 = "aardvark"
swapIfGreater(&s1, &s2)

// Bool doesn’t support the Comparable protocol
// (false is not “less than” or “greater than” true)
// so this won’t compile:
var b1 = true, b2 = false
swapIfGreater(&b1, &b2)
```

At compile time, when `swapIfGreater` is called, Swift looks at the type being used in the slots for the generic placeholder `T` (here either `Int` or `String`), and checks that they meet the requirement (they need to conform to the protocol `Comparable`).  If it does, you can think of it as writing a version of the function specifically for each valid type you pass in:

```
// It’s as if Swift writes two versions of swapIfGreater for you automatically:
func swapIfGreater(inout a: Int, inout b: Int) {
    if a > b {
        (a, b) = (b, a)
    }
}

func swapIfGreater(inout a: String, inout b: String) {
    if a > b {
        (a, b) = (b, a)
    }
}
```

Comment: İf you import Foundation, String is implicitly converted NSString. Since NSString is a class I wonder if S:String throws error in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The code `<S: String>` shouldn't work for the simple reason that String is a struct, and a struct cannot be extended. So the the S is actually an invalid type.

If you are looking to have `c` be an enum you should use `<S: RawRepresentable where S.RawType == String>`.

If you are thinking of adding functionality to the String type you should have `c` be a plain String and then use an extension on String to implement the functionality.

If you are actually wanting to extend a String as an object you should instead extend NSString.

For example:

```
class MyString: NSString {
  // My code
}
```

and then your generic becomes: `<S: NSString>`, which is totally valid.

The downside to extending NSString is the type is now a reference type, however that is just part of Swift, you cannot extend (in terms of inheriting) a struct.

Comment: Why struct cannot be extended? tutorial say "Extensions add new functionality to an existing class, structure, or enumeration type."

Comment: Sorry that was a bad use of words. Structs can be extended using "Extensions". But they cannot be "extended" by inheritance.

The difference is there are special restrictions on "extensions" (e.g. they cannot store new member variables, which would increase the size of the type)